# Combine the list returned by `re.findall()`

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, string-parsing

[append vs. extend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252703/python-append-vs-extend) .I got answer here i just have to use extend keyword instead of append.

```
def extractDollar(line): 
        global mainList
        temp=[]

        #lowercasing all the string
        line=line.lower()

        #storing all word starting with $ in a line in temp
        #then adding that  to existing list mainList
        #to form a single list and removing empty value
        temp= re.findall(r'$\w+',line)

        mainList=mainList+[j for i in zip(mainList,temp) for j in i]
        mainList= filter(None, mainList)

        return line
```

I have a file with multiple string; each string has word starting with $ and I want to store all word starting with $ in a file as a single List (mainList).
I wrote this function to read file line by line. I am getting temp array filled with all value starting with $ in one line but not able to add all the single list returned by re.findall as single main List.

Answer (score 0):

Try `reduce(sum, line)`:

```
def extractDollar(line): 
        global mainList
        temp=[]

        #lowercasing all the string
        line=line.lower()

        #storing all word starting with $ in a line in temp
        #then adding that  to existing list mainList
        #to form a single list and removing empty value
        temp= re.findall(r'$\w+',line)

        mainList=mainList+[j for i in zip(mainList,temp) for j in i]
        mainList= filter(None, mainList)

        return reduce(sum,line)
```

Comment: I got the answer but thanks. I just have to use extend . So mainlList.extend(temp)